# Sublime Text 2 - Key binding for specific language?

Tags: sublimetext2, key-bindings

**Question**

What's the proper way to create a key binding for a specific language?

**Background**

I'd like to insert a semi-colon after each line automatically when working on java files.  I've created a macro to accomplish and have been able to bind it to `super+enter`.  Now I'd like to scope the key binding to just java files.  What am I doing wrong?

```
[
  { 
    "keys": ["super+enter"], "command": "run_macro_file", 
    "args": {"file": "Packages/User/Add Line SemiColon.sublime-macro"},
    "context": [
      { "key": "selector", "operator": "equals", "operand": "source.java" }
    ] 
  }
]
```

Comment: Just a heads up after you fix "equal" . http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/21146-key-binding-context-to-only-react-on-eg-python-code/. If you scroll down through some of the comments, you will see that it doesn't work on OS X (for whatever reason). They have a 'work around'. Though it isn't very good as they basically disable the keybinding for any other languages. But perhaps that's okay for you. The comment you are looking for is from "Oktay Acikalin" Can't tell what platform you are using, but thought I would throw the link up just in case it's relevant.

Comment: @skuroda looks like the fix may be in, I'm on OS X and it's working perfectly now that I fixed the equal issue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're going to love this—the comparison operator that you're looking for isn't `equals`, it's [`equal`](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html#context-operators):

> **Context Operators**
>
> `equal`, `not_equal`— Test for equality.
>
> `regex_match`, `not_regex_match`— Match against a regular expression.
>
> `regex_contains`, `not_regex_contains`— Match against a regular expression (containment).

Change that, and you shouldn't have any more trouble.